# Activiti framework: resultVariableName strange behaviour

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

I've just started with activiti framework. I added dependency to my spring boot app and wanted to
test very simple sequnce flow but I'm stuck with strange behavior.

So, I have 2 simple service without any business logic.

```
@Service
public class Service1{

    public void m(String id) {
        log.info("Service1 Id {}", id);
    }
} 



@Service
public class Service2{

    public void m(String id) {
        log.info("Service2 Id {}", id);
    }
}
```

And xml file with process definition:

```
    <startEvent id="startEvent" name="Start"></startEvent>

    <serviceTask id="service1Task" name="service1"
                 activiti:expression="${service1.m(id)}"
                 activiti:resultVariableName="id">
    </serviceTask>

    <serviceTask id="service2Task" name="service2"
                 activiti:expression="${service2.m(id)}">
    </serviceTask>

    <endEvent id="endEvent" name="End"></endEvent>

    <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startEvent" targetRef="service1Task"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="service1Task" targetRef="service2Task"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="flow3" sourceRef="service2Task" targetRef="endEvent"></sequenceFlow>
```

And I put in some controller:

```
  Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>();
   val id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
   variables.put("id", id);
```

The problem is: for service1 it prints id but for service2 it loses id. In debugger mode in service2 parameter id is empty string for some reason. I cannot understand why...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no need to indicate resultVariableName anywhere. Defined variables will be available anyway.